# Partition is in quorum loss

Tags: azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateful

I have a Service Fabric application that has a stateless web api and a stateful service with two partitions. The stateless web api defines a web api controller and uses `ServiceProxy.Create` to get a remoting proxy for the stateful service. The remoting call puts a message into a reliable queue.

The stateful service will dequeue the messages from the queue every X minutes.

I am looking at the Service Fabric explorer and my application has been in an error state for the past few days. When I drill down into the details the stateful service has the following error:

> Error event: SourceId='System.FM', Property='State'. Partition is in
>   quorum loss.

Looking at the explorer I see that I have my primary replica up and running and it seems like a single ActiveSecondary, but the other two replicas show IdleSecondary and they keep going into a Standby / In Build state. I cannot figure out why this is happening.

What are some of the reasons my other secondaries keep failing to get to an ActiveSecondary state / causing this quorum loss?

[image]

Comment: can you add the output of the powershell command 'Get-ServiceFabricClusterHealth' ?

Comment: It reports that my service and partitions are unhealthy, but does not give any details.

Comment: How many nodes and replicas do you have in configs?

Comment: 5 Node cluster, Min Replica = 2, Target = 3. 2x Partitions (both of them are in this failed state though)

Comment: How many apps do you have in the cluster? Did you update the app before that issue started to occur?

Comment: I had 3 custom apps and just the built in service fabric apps at the time. I hadn't touched this app in over 3 weeks and hadn't really been paying attention to anything in the cluster (it's development and we were focused on other things). Then I took a look at the cluster and noticed it was in quorum loss and had no idea why.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/servicefabric/vlatest/Repair-ServiceFabricPartition?redirectedfrom=msdn
I am not sure of the cause yet, but this may help resolve.  I would test against a non-prod cluster before usage though, as I am not aware of the consequences of rebuilding yet.  particularly the Repair-ServiceFabricPartition -System

Answer (score 1):

Try to reset the cluster.
I was facing the same issue having 1 partition for my service.
The error was fixed with resetting the cluster

Comment: That worked for me last time -- but it seems to come back every so often. -- It amazes me that a cluster with a single node can somehow be in `InQuorumLoss`. -- Like, how the heck did it even happen -- did it lose an argument that it was having with itself??

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the Windows Event Log on the nodes for additional error message?

I had a similar problem, except I was using a ReliableDictionary. Did you properly implement `IEquatable<T>` and `IComparable<T>`? I had a similar problem because my `T` had a dictionary field, and I was calling `Equals` on a dictionary directly, instead of comparing the keys and values. Same thing for `GetHashCode`.

The clue in the event logs was this message: `Assert=Cannot update an item that does not exist (null).` - it only happened when I edited a key ReliableDictionary.

[image]

Comment: It's been a long time since it has occurred but I will try this next time.

Answer (score 0):

```
Repair-ServiceFabricPartition -All
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servicefabric/repair-servicefabricpartition?view=azureservicefabricps